# save a Git message in a java variable

Tags: java, git

I'm working on Java to deal with Git data, and I need to save a Git message of each commit in a Java variable.

How can I do that?

Comment: JGIT / EGIT? .. http://www.jgit.org/

Answer (score 1):

start a process in Java. Capture the output of `git log`. Or try egit.

Answer (score 0):

use jgit, a library written in pure Java implementation of git.

iterate over `Git.open(...).log().call()`